# Add icon image to a popup box with description

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to add an icon image in the popup box with a description of the icon. Please help with where I add the code to insert the image before the description. I also want the popup box to be used "onclick" user clicks button and popup box opens. The Code below opens box when page opens.  My code is listed below, any help appreciated.

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload = function () {alert("Close PDF document.\nSave PDF Document\nMerge new PDF.\nDelete PDF pages\n" ); }
</script>';
?>
```

Comment: An alert will not render an image. To set this up onclick you need to add an onclick event to the entity that will be clicked. You could use a different type of messaging like jQuery Dialog.

Comment: An alert also doesn't let you choose options. It's more of an information box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic dialog (with jQuery):

```
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript alert function doesn't allows to change the icon of the dialog.

To do that you should use other library as Emilio said on the previous answer. Or look to other jquery plugin which allows you to create popups with a custom image.